# How to make an effective sampling from a database of text documents?

Tags: dataset, databases, sampling

Problem: I want to know methods to perform an effective sampling from a database.
The size of the database is about `250K` text documents and in this case each text document is related to some majors (Electrical Engineering, Medicine and so on). So far I have seen some simple techniques like [Simple random sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample) and [Stratified sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling); however, I don't think it's a good idea to apply them for the following reasons:

- In the case of simple random sample, for instance, there are a few documents in the database that talk about majors like Naval Engineering or Arts. Therefore I think they are less likely to be sampled with this method but I would like to have some samples of every major as possible.
- In the case of stratified sampling, most of the documents talk about more than one major so I cannot divide the database in subgroups because they will not be mutually exclusive, at least for the case in which each major is a subgroup.

Finally, I cannot use the whole database due to expensive computational cost processing. So I would really appreciate any suggestions on other sampling methods. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I would consider, at least, two **approaches**, as follows.

- **Graph sampling.** If you can (and it makes sense to) model your *population* (database of text documents) as a graph, then consider *graph sampling*. Check [this relevant answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/128661/31372) of mine on the topic on *Cross Validated* site (contains many references - I would start with [this nice overview paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5865)).
- **Topic modeling.** Another alternative is topic modeling (also referred to as topic models). See [this introductory paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/Blei2012.pdf) as well as [this more detailed paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiLafferty2009.pdf) on the subject. Also, take a look at [this interesting paper](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~lmyao/papers/fast-topic-model10.pdf) on topic modeling of *streaming* documents (or other situations, such as large databases, when unsupervised solutions make more sense). Finally, speaking about **software** for topic modeling, while many options do exist, I suggest investigating [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu), which is an interesting Java-based software package for *"statistical natural language processing, document classification, clustering, topic modeling, information extraction, and other machine learning applications to text"*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going to check them all and update my situation later on.

Comment: @KevinBelloMedina: You're welcome. Note that development of MALLET has been moved to GitHub: https://github.com/mimno/Mallet.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do simple random sampling, but maintain counts of the labels you've seen thus far. When you reach quota for a label, you'll need to cull all documents with that label from the pool, and sample from the remaining documents without that label.

I *think* this will be a fair way of getting a stratified sample when your labels are overlapping.